# Why Twig extend tag sometimes doesn't see some variables?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

In Symfony2 i created simple action:

```
public function testAction()
{        
    return $this->render('TestBundle::test.html.twig', array(
        'testBool'    => true,
        'testTplPath' => 'TestBundle::base.html.twig'
    ));
}
```

base.html.twig:

```
<html><body>{% block content %}{% endblock %}</body></html>
```

And now i have problem with extends tag in my test.html.twig template, if i use simple string in this tag like this: `{% extends 'TestBundle::base.html.twig' %}` everything works fine but this dosn't work: `{% extends testTplPath %}`. Second example throws me error: `Variable "testTplPath" does not exist in TestBundle::test.html.twig at line 1`.

This works fine: `{% extends testBool ? 'TestBundle::base.html.twig' : 'blah' %}`

This throws exception: `{% extends testBool ? testTplPath : 'blah' %}` - `Variable "testBool" does not exist in TestBundle::test.html.twig at line 1` (notice that Twig throws this time exception about `testBool` variable - why?!)

According to TWIG documentation all examples abowe should work and i don't know what i did wrong.

I made a lot of tests and i can't figure any pattern when exteds see variables and when not.

I currently use Twig v1.16.0 and Symfony 2.5.4

---

**Update**: I noticed antoher strange thing, if I put into `testTplPath` valid path or create any other dynamic experssion which returns valid path i got `Variable "[first var in expression]" does not exist` exception but if it return invalid path i got: `Unable to find template "TestBundle::SomeInvalidTemplate.html.twig"`.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the expression with brackets? `(testBool ? testTplPath : 'blah')` ?

Comment: I tried it now and it doesn't help :/

Comment: what happens if you use `{% set base_template = (testBool|default(false) ? testTplPath|default('TestBundle::base.html.twig') : 'SomeOtherBundle::base.html.twig') %}{% extends base_template %}` ?

Comment: `Variable "base_template" does not exist`

Comment: you did clear your cache after changing the template, right?

Comment: I don't think you can use a string variable in the extends statement.  Look here:  http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html#dynamic-inheritance {% extends some_var %} only works if some_var is a Twig_Template object.  There are other ways to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: I found problem :-/ In template test.html.twig i had also global form and I was convinced that this form is not important but... https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5284 It looks that this bug is still not fixed.

Comment: @Cerad I'm actually pretty sure I've used a twig global ( i.e. registered via `twig.globals.base_template`) with `{% extends base_template %}` in one of my past projects! I think twig resolves the variable first, and checks the type (Twig_Template|string|array) afterwards ... trying to find the project to evaluate this.

Comment: @nifi - You are probably right.  I did not try it myself.  Looks like he running into that _self thingee.  I still think he might be able to use: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#template-naming-and-locations and not need to change the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

In template test.html.twig i had also global form and I was convinced that this form is not important but... https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5284 It looks that this bug is still not fixed completely. I removed _self from {% form_theme form with [_self, form_theme] %} and everything works as expected now.